# javascript replace issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

i have buildt a small highlight script, this script has a results tags, which means that you can enter words in a input field and it will be displayed as clickable tags, the tags are created by a whitespace(enter space and a new tag will form). You can click on the tags to remove the results from the input and text.

The issue, if you enter a single letter and click it to remove it, it removes all letters in all of the search words(so click on a single a all of the a's are beeing removed from the search input)

the code

```
$('a').live('click',function(){
var searchPhrase = $(this).text();
$('input').val(
    $('input').val().replace(searchPhrase,'')
);
})
```

i use this piece of code to simple remove the matched text from the input.

What do i need, well the tags should be removed if they match, so i need to include a regex begin of a string pattern....i think.

Found the solution:

```
var reg = new RegExp("\\b"+ searchPhrase +"\\b", "g");
```

Comment: i know but how to merge this with a variable?

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer below, so we can take this off the unanswered list?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use: [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for [JavaScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html), instead of JavaScript plain search method.

Comment: i know but i use this because its easy for me, not a big fan of regex ;)